# What's the difference between source.StartWith(x).Replay(1) and source.Publish(x)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Given a sequence, `IObservable<int> source;`, is there a difference between:

```
var published = source.Publish(0);
var publishedConnection = published.Connect();
```

and

```
var replayed = source.StartWith(0).Replay(1);
var replayedConnection = replayed.Connect();
```

As far as I'm aware, they're very similar. They both have a default value of zero, on subscription, the observer will immediately receive the last value from `source`, and all further values from `source` are pushed out to the subscriber.

I have a vague inkling that I read somewhere (which I can't find now) that if `source` were to complete, `published` would not pass any value to new subscribers, but instead complete immediately, whereas `replayed` would still replay the last value to new subscribers before completing.

Have I remembered this correctly (and can anyone find a source stating so), and are there any other differences between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference you have listed is accurate. `Replay` replays whereas `Publish` just publishes. I checked this by writing five lines of code. There are no other significant differences. The source code is also available at http://rx.codeplex.com - although I admit it's not readily decipherable to those unfamiliar with it.

Code:

```
var source = Observable.Return(1);

// comment out as appropriate:
// this gives no output
var conn = source.Publish(0);
// this gives 1
var conn = source.StartWith(0).Replay(1);

conn.Connect();

conn.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Although a technical detail as you know, it may be worth noting that the primary difference between these operators is their purpose: The particular overload of `Publish` in the question is designed to hide a `BehaviorSubject` and `Replay` is designed to hide a `ReplaySubject`.